# Tier abstraction of data in Go

Tags: go

I am going to create a project in Go, but I want to separate my tiers. My goal is create a package that has code something like the DAO pattern, i.e. I wish that my caller should only communicate with the interface of the service (which might be another project) and not with the implementation. This is to avoid the situation of a future change to the database, the caller should not change and should be transparent to this change.

I was thinking of creating a project db that contains a file called persistence with a package persistence as well

http://play.golang.org/p/O9b93F4LJp

```
package persistence

// Interface that have the CRUD which I need to use from service(another project)
type Recorder interface {
    Selectkey([]byte) (err error)
    Insert([]byte, []byte) (err error)
    Update([]byte, []byte) (err error)
    Delete([]byte) (err error)
}

// Struct for Oracle
type ManageDataOracle struct {
}
// Struct for binaryTree
type ManageDataBInaryTree struct {
}
// Struct for MongoDB
type ManageDataMongoDb struct {
}

// Implemtations for Oracle
func (memory *ManageDataOracle) SelectKey(pKey []byte) error {
    // Logic for Oracle Here
    return nil
}
func (memory *ManageDataOracle) Insert(pKey []byte, pValue []byte) error {
        // Logic for Oracle Here
    return nil
}
func (memory *ManageDataOracle) Update(pKey []byte, pValue []byte) error {
    // Logic for Oracle Here
    return nil
}

func (memory *ManageDataOracle) Delete(pKey []byte) error {
    // Logic for Oracle Here
    return nil
}

// Implemtations for Binary Tree
func (memory *ManageDataBInaryTree) SelectKey(pKey []byte) error {
    // Logic for Binary tree Here
    return nil
}
func (memory *ManageDataBInaryTree) Insert(pKey []byte, pValue []byte) error {
        // Logic for Binary tree Here
    return nil
}
func (memory *ManageDataBInaryTree) Update(pKey []byte, pValue []byte) error {
    // Logic for Binary tree Here
    return nil
}    

func (memory *ManageDataBInaryTree) Delete(pKey []byte) error {
    // Logic for Binary tree Here
    return nil
}

// Implemtations for Mongo DB
func (memory *ManageDataMongoDb) SelectKey(pKey []byte) error {
    // Logic for MongoDB Here
    return nil
}
func (memory *ManageDataMongoDb) Insert(pKey []byte, pValue []byte) error {
        // Logic for MongoDB Here
    return nil
}
func (memory *ManageDataMongoDb) Update(pKey []byte, pValue []byte) error {
    // Logic for MongoDB Here
    return nil
}

func (memory *ManageDataMongoDb) Delete(pKey []byte) error {
    // Logic for MongoDB Here
    return nil
}
```

Any advice on how to do this separation of concepts, or how the previous code should be called from another project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track but different persistence mechanisms will use different key types (for example an integer in an oracle and a string-like identifier in mongo).

The serialization of your data into `[]byte` should be handled by the abstraction layer because different underlying persistence engines will use different representations of your data. Consider for instance an integer and it's endianness.

Hence I would change the signatures of your interface to the following:

```
type Recorder interface {
    SelectByKey(interface{}) error
    DeleteByKey(interface{}) error
    Insert(interface{}, interface{}) error
    Update(interface{}, interface{}) error
}
```

this way you can also `panic` inside, say `SelectKey` if the given key is not of the correct type for a specific implementation. This wouldn't be possible if you serialized your key beforehand and would lead to trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:

https://github.com/qiangxue/golang-restful-starter-kit

> This starter kit is designed to get you up and running with a project
>   structure optimal for developing RESTful services in Go. The kit
>   promotes the best practices that follow the SOLID principles and
>   encourage writing clear and idiomatic Go code.
>
> The kit provides the following features right out of the box
>
> RESTful endpoints in the widely accepted format Standard CRUD
>   operations of a database table JWT-based authentication Application
>   configuration via environment variable and configuration file
>   Structured logging with contextual information Panic handling and
>   proper error response generation Automatic DB transaction handling
>   Data validation Full test coverage